# Regex - Expression for 6 digits or 9 digits not less or between or more

Tags: regex

I have to write a regex that detects either 6 digits or 9 digits - meaning:

```
ID 123 - it should not meet the regext as it is 3 digits
ID 1234 - it should not meet the regext as it is 4 digits
ID 12345 - it should not meet the regext as it is 5 digits
ID 123456 - it should meet the regex it is 6 digits <==========
ID 1234567 - it should not meet the regext as it is 7 digits
ID 12345678 - it should not meet the regext as it is 8 digits
ID 123456789 - it should meet the regext as it is 9 digits <==========
ID 1234567890 - it should not meet the regext as it is 10 digits
ID 12345678901 - it should not meet the regext as it is 11 digits
```

and so on... you got the idea?

Can anyone help me with the regex for this one?

Comment: Try `^ID (\d{6}|\d{9})$`

Answer (score 3):

You may try to use this pattern:

```
\b(\d{6}|\d{9})\b
```

Answer (score 2):

Or another one:

```
\b\d{6}(?:\d{3})?\b
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GXODNe/1/)

- `\b` matches a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `\d{6}` six digits (`\d` is a [short](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for digit)
- `(?:\d{3})?` an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) containing another three digits

Answer (score 1):

If the ID part should be matched, you could use an alternation to match either 6 or 9 digits.

Use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string or add word boundaries `\b` to the beginning and the end of the pattern.

The digits are in the first capturing group.

```
^ID (\d{6}|\d{9})$
```